# Freemarker applying a built-in function to sequence items - ...?cap_first?join()

Tags: freemarker, sequences, built-in

Is there a way in Freemarker to apply a string function on sequence items like this?

```
${['hi','folks']?cap_first?join(' ')
```

I would like the result to be `Hi Folks`.
Or do I have to use `<#list>`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `#list` currently

```
<#list ['hi', 'folks'] as i>${i?cap_first}<#sep> </#list>
```